# Hot to stop and resume game loop in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm working on a small android game. It's using a game Activity to start the main loop, which opens up a glSurfaceView. The surfaceview is setup using a renderer. The game runs as intended.

onCreate method from gameActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);
}
```

GameView class:

```
public class GameView extends GLSurfaceView {
private GameRenderer renderer;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    renderer = new GameRenderer();

    this.setRenderer(renderer);


}
```

I'm not sure how to properly end the game. Once the conditions for ending the game are properly met, I tried starting a new endscreen activity from inside the renderer, which causes the app to crash. How do I properly close this game loop?

Comment: As noted in the answer, use the `setRenderMode()` method.  For an example, see Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).  It changes the render mode when the game is won or lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can pause the rendering by **changing the render-mode** to this:

```
GLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

If RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY is used, the surface will only redraw itself upon calling `requestRender()`

When you want to **resume** rendering, call:

```
GLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Alternatively, you can just provide a **boolean-flag** that will prevent further rendering when being set to false.